Is there any faster way to getPoolKeys from Solana Raydium?
Currently, I am fetching all liquidity-related data from Raydium API. (https://api.raydium.io/v2/sdk/liquidity/mainnet.json)
And then matching with my desired token address to filter the right PoolKeys. But this process is taking too much time.
Here is my code snippet
// Pass both token addresses (mint), and it will return the data of the pool of those tokens.
const getPoolKeys = async (tokenA, tokenB) => {
    const liquidityJsonResp = await fetch(liquidityFile);
    if (!liquidityJsonResp.ok) return
    const liquidityJson = await liquidityJsonResp.json()
    const allPoolKeysJson = [...(liquidityJson?.official ?? []), ...(liquidityJson?.unOfficial ?? [])]

    const poolData = allPoolKeysJson.find(
        (i) => (i.baseMint === tokenA && i.quoteMint === tokenB) || (i.baseMint === tokenB && i.quoteMint === tokenA)
    )
    if (!poolData) return null
    return jsonInfo2PoolKeys(poolData)
};


Is there any way to do it faster?

I was facing the same problem. Adding the repo, how I solve the problem. So far it is a stable and faster solution then others.
https://github.com/CoreDevsLtd/getPools_solana_raydium
